# Speed up bmp image loading in python

Tags: python, performance, load, bmp

I am reading in a 24 bpp bitmap image in Python. I am using the struct module and am reading in my file byte by byte and storing the BGR elements in my multidimensional array. See code below:

```
            char = fileObject.read(1)
            self.blue[w][h] = struct.unpack('=B', char)[0]
            char = fileObject.read(1)
            self.green[w][h] = struct.unpack('=B', char)[0]
            char = fileObject.read(1)
            self.red[w][h] = struct.unpack('=B', char)[0]
```

This takes a long time (10 seconds for a 2732 x 1536 pixel image).

I want to speed it up but I'm not sure how. I was thinking something like this:

```
            threeChar = fileObject.read(3)
            self.blue[w][h] = ((threeChar >> 8) << 8) #knock of not-needed bits
            self.green[w][h] = ((threeChar >> 4) << 8)
            self.red[w][h] = (threeChar << 8)
```

I'm not really sure how to go about speeding things up here. Can you give me any advice? What is slow here and why is it slow? How do I speed it up?

Comment: did you try [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) already?

Comment: @MaxU I'm reading in the bmp without any libraries because I wanted to.